# How to sum effectively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

Before I start, I apologize for a bad title but I could not come up with one that describes my question in a satisfying way. If you come up with a better title, I will gladly switch.

Suppose I have an `Account` model and a `Transaction` model, and I would like to implement a `Account#days_since_balance_was_atleast` method, taking a sum as its sole parameter. What would be an effective way to do this?

Here comes some sample code:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :account_id, :created_at, :amount
    belongs_to :account
    # Some logic to update account balance at creation...
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_presence_of :balance 
   has_many :transactions

   def days_since_balance_was_atleast(sum)
       #How should I implement this?
   end
end
```

Should I use some smart SQL fragment, or perhaps ActiveRecord::Calculations? Loading all transactions and stepping backwards manually seems like a very bad idea (especially since there can be lots of transactions). And if I am stuck with the last approach, do you think it would be smart to retrieve the transactions in batches.

**What it should produce (Updated):**

```
# We have the following transactions 
# (time is unimportant for the result unless it is 00.00)
# Days ago  0   1   2   3   4  5   6   7
# Amount    -20 10 -60 -30 50 50 -100 100

account.balance == 0             # true
days_since_balance_was(100) == 3 # true
```

So, how would you solve this problem?

Comment: I think that you need to explain what days_since_balance_was_atleast is supposed to return with more detail. Maybe adding an example with values and the desired result

Comment: I fear for my life as I type this, but it seems like a good use case for a stored procedure (don't flame me bro!).

Otherwise, I think find_by_sql is going to be your friend here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be that hard, using SQL join. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT t1.time
FROM transactions t1
LEFT JOIN transactions t2 ON t2.time < t1.time
HAVING SUM(t2.amount) >= 100
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.time
ORDER BY t1.time
LIMIT 1
```

Either implement it using AR, or create a view in your database.

Comment: I see I'll need to fresh up my SQL knowledge. But wouldn't this code work in the wrong order (from the oldest transaction and onwards, instead of from the latest)? Switching to ``ORDER BY t1.time DESC`` and ``ON t2.time > t1.time`` seems more right to me. I'll come back with an update after I've done some experimenting, but this definitely seems like a good candidate.

Comment: You're right, I misread your question (but then again, now I feel honoured, knowing that someone has read my answer thoroughly enough to find a bug in it!) :) Anyway, I think this is pretty much standard SQL (except for perhaps `LIMIT` clause).

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. See my own answer for a full working SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Consider keeping the balance as a separate field. Then your problem shifts from a difficult summing problem to one of simply keeping the balance field consistent with the transactions

Comment: I don't think that helps to find the date a particular (dynamic) balance was hit though does it?

Comment: @Bobby B, if the current balance is greater than the target, find the latest date when the balance is less than the target. If the balance is less than the target, find the latest date when the balance is greater than the target

Comment: Do you suggest that I should keep balance as a separate field in the transactions table (populated with the account balance at the transaction time, perhaps)?

Comment: +1 @Daniel The Inserts are always made in chronological order? If so i would suggest a separate balance field in transactions. If not you have to update the balance field in every newer transaction too. So you have to decide if you can accept sometimes slower inserts for a way faster days_since_balance_was_atleast implementation.

Comment: @Daniel, Yes, that is one way (maybe with a trigger or stored procedure). If there are a lot of transactions per day it may be ok for you to keep the balances in a different table and add one row per customer per day - but then you might miss the case if the balance goes above the target and then drops below in the same day

Answer (score 0):

Daniel,

That is fairly tricky.  Does the sum have to be dynamic (I'm assuming so).  If not, you could capture the date that a threshold is hit and use that for some simple date logic.

Assuming you have to go dynamic though, I would load the entire transaction collection and iterate through it in reverse keeping track of the sum until you break your threshold.  I'm more comfortable in a database world than I am in app development, and I'm not sure how you would solve that in the db layer without using syntax that is specific to a particular dbe - which means it's probably not something you would want to do via ActiveRecord.

Good luck - tough problem!

BB

Comment: I also considered it a tough problem, that is why I asked about it here ;) My current approach is the one you describe in your answer, but I really would like to see a faster one.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change Mladens code into this working snippet:

```
SELECT t1.time
FROM transactions t1
LEFT JOIN transactions t2 ON t2.time >= t1.time
WHERE t1.account_id=9 AND t2.account_id=9
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.time
HAVING SUM(-t2.amount) >= 100
ORDER BY t1.time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I will accept Mladen's answer with a pointer to this one, as it was the one that led to the result, unless someone comes up with an even smarter method. I'm not sure whether this is the best method, but it avoids the heavy work of instantiating lots of ActiveRecord objects and lets the DB do the tough work.